Hypersurface with one singularity
A statement goes like

$H\in\mathbb{P}^n$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$ admitting only one singularity $p\in H$ with multiplicity $m$. We may assume the (homogeneous) coordinate of the singularity is $(1:0:\dots:0)\in\mathbb{P}^n$.

I have no idea why we can assume this way. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Just take a (projective) linear change of coordinates on $\Bbb P^n$ to move $p$ to the desired point.

I was thinking why we could assert that there's only one component of the coordinates that is non zero (I'm new to alg geo. Sorry for the stupid question)

A more general form of your question which is helpful to think about @IlPreteRosso is "how much does a projective transformation allow me to assume?" Many proofs in algebraic geometry begin by using coordinate changes to make convenient expressions. Getting a feel for this will probably save you a lot of headache over time.

@A.ThomasYerger I'll look into this projective transformation thing o7

HINT: Think about what you can do with an invertible linear transformation on $\Bbb A^{n+1}$.

@TedShifrin I feel soo stupid now .. It was just the problem of not being familiar with the language used in AG so I got confused

@A.ThomasYerger can I say linear projective transformation preserves singularity because singularity corresponds to the number of the leading zeros of the tylor expansion (which is the polynomial itself) and it is invariant of a linear tranformation.

In answer to your last question, yes.

@TedShifrin Thank you so much :)
